# UIAlertController as a Utility that accepts function parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I have this UIAlertController as a utility that accepts two paremeters, the title and the content. I want to modify the "confirm" button. I want to duplicate this utility and add another parameter the will execute a specific function.

```
-(UIAlertController *) modalWithTitle : (NSString *) title andContent: (NSString *) content{

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: title message:content preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){}];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    return alert;
}
```

Example code :

```
UIAlertController *alert =[[ModalController alloc] modalWithTitle:@"Error" andContent:@"Network unavailable."
        andAction:<ENTER FUNCTION TO EXECUTE HERE>];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Don't use a function, use a closure (completion block).

Comment: Can I ask how is that used? and sample of it? I just want to execute something when the user clicks ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
+ (UIAlertController *)modalWithTitle:(NSString *)title andContent:(NSString *)content andHandler:(void (^)(UIAlertAction *))handler {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: title message:content preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:handler];
    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    return alert;
}
```

Usage:

```
void (^handler)(UIAlertAction *) = ^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // code to execute
};
[[ModalController alloc] modalWithTitle:@"title" andContent:@"content" andHandler:handler];
```

Another approach:

```
+ (UIAlertController *)modalWithTitle:(NSString *)title andContent:(NSString *)content andHandler:(void (^)(void))handler {
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:content preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        handler();
    }];
    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    return alert;
}
```

Usage:

```
void (^block)(void) = ^{
    // code to execute
};
[[ModalController alloc] modalWithTitle:@"title" andContent:@"content" andHandler:block];
```

Comment: Tried the first method and it worked well! Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: @EdBer Consider accepting the answer if it fits your needs.